# Kubernetes PV and PVC not working as expected

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc

I have a Spring Boot application deployed on Kubernetes, which contains an API that writes to a file. It works, but I'm facing an issue with it. When I run the API, the file gets created by the container that handles the API, and it gets created in its '/home' directory. Unfortunately, the file gets deleted when the container terminates, which is not ideal since I need this file to be used by another API.

So, I tried to implement PV and PVC like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: my-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi  
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce  
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain  
  hostPath:
    path: "C:/Users/HP/Desktop/fold/dataset.arff"  

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: my-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

and I adjusted my deployment file

```
          volumeMounts:  
            - name: data-volume
              mountPath: /home 

      volumes:
        - name: data-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: my-pvc
```

when describing the pvc I think there is no issue

```
  Normal  ExternalProvisioning   38m   persistentvolume-controller                                                  waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "docker.io/hostpath" or manually created by system administrator
  Normal  Provisioning           38m   docker.io/hostpath_storage-provisioner_f7d192aa-89bb-4f5b-a228-f1f41819f16e  External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "default/my-pvc"
  Normal  ProvisioningSucceeded  38m   docker.io/hostpath_storage-provisioner_f7d192aa-89bb-4f5b-a228-f1f41819f16e  Successfully provisioned volume pvc-58dbd3af-7641-42bc-8e7c-cef90966b699
```

and the same thing for pv

```
 k describe pv my-pv
Name:            my-pv
Labels:          <none>
Annotations:     <none>
Finalizers:      [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:
Status:          Available
Claim:
Reclaim Policy:  Retain
Access Modes:    RWO
VolumeMode:      Filesystem
Capacity:        1Gi
Node Affinity:   <none>
Message:
Source:
    Type:          HostPath
    Path:          C:/Users/HP/Desktop/fold/dataset.arff
    HostPathType:
Events:            <none>
```

```
 k describe pv my-pv
Name:            my-pv
Labels:          <none>
Annotations:     <none>
Finalizers:      [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:
Status:          Available
Claim:
Reclaim Policy:  Retain
Access Modes:    RWO
VolumeMode:      Filesystem
Capacity:        1Gi
Node Affinity:   <none>
Message:
Source:
    Type:          HostPath 
    Path:          C:/Users/HP/Desktop/fold/dataset.arff
    HostPathType:
Events:            <none>
```

after I did all this I can't see the file get created in my host machine directory what Im doing wrong ?

Comment: You should usually let the cluster create PersistentVolumes for you; don't do it by hand.  There are a lot of practical problems with trying to share files between container like this especially once you have more than one node.  Can you store the data somewhere like a relational database; can the consumer get the data via an HTTP GET request?

Comment: Yes the consumer can get the data via an HTTP GET request  .